# Got error "There is an error in xml document (1 40)" while doing DeSerialization of xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an asp.net 2.0 website.
I am using Deserialize method to deserialize the xml.
I got this error

> "There is an error in xml document (1 40)"

```
 public List<Test_XML> DeSerializeObject(string pstrXML)
{
   List<Test_XML> _obj = new List<Test_XML>();
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pstrXML))
        {
            XmlSerializer _xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Test_XML>));
            StringReader _strReader = new StringReader(pstrXML);
            _obj = (List<Test_XML>)_xmlSerializer.Deserialize(_strReader);
        }
        return _obj;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        throw e; 
    }
    finally
    {
        _obj = null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to include that bit of XML Document.

Comment: You can check it quickly also, open your XML in browser and if it opens up correctly then you might need to look into code, but I guess you have problem with your XML.

Comment: Also, I suspect the error message actually contains more information than that. And you could make your method about half the size by removing the pointless try/catch/finally block - it's basically equivalent to just having the body of the `try` block (but worse, as when you rethrow the exception you're actually losing useful stacktrace information). You very rarely need to set variables to null like this - certainly not local variables at the end of a method.

Comment: My XML opens up correctly in browser.

Answer (score 0):

try below thing..i havnt checked it though and still not working then there is something wrong in your XML file

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Test_XML>));

    List<Test_XML> _obj;

    using(var stream = new StringReader(pstrXML))
    using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        _obj= (List<Test_XML>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```